# Raspberry PI 3B+ losing connnection

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+, connection

I have a problem with my raspberry. I can connect to it using putty(ssh) or VNC Viewer, but after few minutes the connection drops.

I still see it listed when i go to "connected devices" on my router page.

I've tried to use both ethernet cable connection and wireless connection from router to the board.

Can you guys give me some advice what to do?

I'm not running any advanced softwere on pi, it happens even when I dont do anything.
For example, I just connect to raspberry with VNC right after powering up the board. After about 10 minutes VNC Viewer disconnects and gives message "The connection was closed remotely".

I'm using 2,5 Amp power supply.

When I lose connection to VNC/putty, I also cannot ping raspberry from my cmd, but I still see it in list of connected devices on my router webpage.

Comment: There are logs that could be checked and perhaps its a overheating problem? And that you can see the device on the router is depending on what lease time it has on DHCP and that can be everything from minutes to days. So you need to investigate and provide more facts.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot this issue a bit more. No ping response sounds like a networking issue, but there are numerous possibilities. Please tell us how you have configured your network; i.e. have you changed any settings in the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I didn't make any changes in /etc/dhcpcd.conf file. I also checked temperatures on my board and they are close to 50 degrees. I also checked my raspberry on other router and other network with new raspbian system loaded and it was working good, so I think my problem is now solved. But I am trying to use Xenomai on my PI and it starts to loosing connection when I am using deploy command from that tutorial: http://www.simplerobot.net/2018/06/rpi23-deploy-xenomai-kernel.html

Comment: I also get error in my router logs: Illegal - Dropped FORWARD packet: SRC=2620:01ec:0c11:0000:0000:0000:0000:0200 MAC=17:10:8D:48:09:86;CM-MAC=ac:22:05:75:2a:77;CMTS-MAC=00:17:10:8d:48:09;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.0;